# How to screen mirror android phone to Ubuntu PC?

Tags: 16.04, android, screen, remote

I need to screen mirror my android phone to Ubuntu PC.
Is there any tool or package available in Ubuntu to do this?

Comment: what version of ubuntu

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: try following this article : https://www.osradar.com/how-to-cast-android-screen-in-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 19):

There are several solutions
Here are the two bests to me

Best but harder: **[scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/)** (Screen mirror and device control via USB and TCP/IP): *This application provides display and control of Android 
devices connected on USB (or over TCP/IP)*

- The Android device requires at least API 21 (Android 5.0).
- Make sure you enabled adb debugging on your device(s). On some devices, you also need to enable an additional option to control it using keyboard and mouse.
- Install scrcpy from snap or from github `snap install scrcpy`
- Configure
- Connect

A [good article](https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc/) document on how to do this.

Quick & Easy: **[Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en_US)** on Android device & a browser on Linux PC

- Install AirDroid app on Android device
- Connect a Linux Pc browser to device
- Use (from Linux PC) the Airdroid Screenshot feature

Feature is available with free use and without any account to online service.

[image: airdroid-screenshot]

Comment: who said scrcpy is hard it's the easiest, just need two commands to get started.

Comment: I just installed it with `apt install scrcpy` and it worked without any configuration after enabling debugging mode.

Comment: Both sound good, but my screen is broken and so I can't enable adb debugging etc.

Comment: I got stuck on `scrcpy`, it's really hard and impossible for rooted devices.  However `AirDroid` is really nice, and I make it run in 10 minutes.

Answer (score -4):

Install Chromium web browser. Oon the far top right corner tap the vertical row of 3 dots and look for *Cast*. If the two devices are on the same wifi and compatible you'll be able to select the PC.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: There are some prerequisites & thats not what asked